# Unable to build IOS - Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 65

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am trying to build IOS app using Nativescript. Getting the below error:

/Users/realsecure/Documents/pro/healcareofficeapp/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'SCSiriWaveformView' from project 'Pods')
/Users/realsecure/Documents/pro/healcareofficeapp/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'MDFTextAccessibility' from project 'Pods')
/Users/realsecure/Documents/pro/healcareofficeapp/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'MDFInternationalization' from project 'Pods')
/Users/realsecure/Documents/pro/healcareofficeapp/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'MBProgressHUD' from project 'Pods')
/Users/realsecure/Documents/pro/healcareofficeapp/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'DKCamera' from project 'Pods')
/Users/realsecure/Documents/pro/healcareofficeapp/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'BEMCheckBox' from project 'Pods')
/Users/realsecure/Documents/pro/healcareofficeapp/platforms/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: MobileCoreServices has been renamed. Use CoreServices instead. (in target 'IQMediaPickerController' from project 'Pods')
/Users/realsecure/Documents/pro/healcareofficeapp/platforms/ios/healcareofficeapp.xcodeproj: warning: Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked and embedded framework 'TNSCore.framework' was built for iOS + iOS Simulator. (in target 'healcareofficeapp' from project 'healcareofficeapp')
/Users/realsecure/Documents/pro/healcareofficeapp/platforms/ios/healcareofficeapp.xcodeproj: warning: Building for iOS Simulator, but the linked and embedded framework 'TNSSideDrawer.framework' was built for iOS + iOS Simulator. (in target 'healcareofficeapp' from project 'healcareofficeapp')
Command xcodebuild failed with exit code 65

Trace of build is pasted, I have tried creating Podfile in AppResources/IOS. Also tried changing it under platforms directory. But still build fails.